# SQL prepared statement insert into database as uppercase

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this function which inserts to my database some values. Values are inserted just fine but i am trying to insert them in upper case which doesn't work. If i use `print_r` after the `for loop` values are printed in uppercase. But in my database it is not stored as uppercase. Has anyone experienced an issue like this before?

```
function tryToInsertRow($mCurrentRowData){

    global $connection;

   // Make Data Uppercase
   for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($mCurrentRowData); $i++){
      $mCurrentRowData[$i] = strtoupper($mCurrentRowData[$i]);
   }



    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO main_db (contact_id, customer_code, customer_name, territory, firstname, lastname, contact_type_description, contact_is_primary, mailing_street, mailing_postal_code, mailing_city, mailing_country, email, mobile_phone, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_insert)) {


        // bind parameters for markers
        if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssdsssssss", $mCurrentRowData[0] ,$mCurrentRowData[1] ,$mCurrentRowData[2] ,$mCurrentRowData[3] , $mCurrentRowData[4] ,$mCurrentRowData[5] ,$mCurrentRowData[6] ,$mCurrentRowData[7] ,$mCurrentRowData[8] ,$mCurrentRowData[9] ,$mCurrentRowData[10] ,$mCurrentRowData[11] ,$mCurrentRowData[12] ,$mCurrentRowData[13] ,$mCurrentRowData[14])) {
            error_log(mysqli_error($connection));
            return false;
        }

        //execute query
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            error_log(mysqli_error($connection));
            return false;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return true;

    } else {
        error_log(mysqli_error($connection));
        return false;
    }


}
```

Main db creation :

```
CREATE TABLE `main_db` (
 `contact_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `customer_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `customer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `territory` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact_type_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact_is_primary` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailing_street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailing_postal_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailing_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mailing_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mobile_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_processed` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `contact_id` (`contact_id`,`customer_code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What does `$mCurrentRowData` look like please?

Comment: Can you also provide "SHOW CREATE TABLE main_db" please? (looking to see variable type, charsets, and collations (sp?))

Comment: @gfunk it brings only the first two lines, `CREATE TABLE `main_db` (
 `contact_id` varchar(25...` . Can't see it even via inspect. Any other command?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Using phpMyAdmin? There's a "Full text" you can select under "Settings" after performing the query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `[0] => 123
    [1] => 123   
    [2] => LEADERS
    [3] => 123     
    [4] => NEETHAN
    [5] => 
    [6] => ASSISTANT
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 58 STREET
    [9] => 123 123
    [10] => LONDON
    [11] => UNITED KINGDOM
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] =>`

Replaced some numbers with "123"

Comment: @gfunk edited question

Comment: @Qirel thanks, good to know - edited question.

Comment: There's also `UPPER()` in MySQL if you want to do it in the query, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: @Qirel Yes, i use it on my `SELECT` statements. But just happened to see that if i try to insert them from the beggining into uppercase it doesn't work that's why i posted the question.

Comment: Is that `$mCurrentRowData` before or after the attempt to upper case all of the array? A before and after would be nice

Comment: @RiggsFolly That function is inserting the data, and before inserting i strtoupper() them. So i guess it's before..is there any difference if i change `"sssssssdsssssss"` to `"SSSSSSSdSSSSSSS"` ?

Comment: I was just interested to know if the loop that uppercases all the array was working on all occurances and therefore we could disregard that phase and start looking for the issues somewhere else

Comment: @RiggsFolly the loop that uppercases is successful for every `$mCurrentRowData` because i used `print_r` and the whole data was in uppercase but not in database (not sure if that's helpful to what you said)